# Java Swing moving in 3d Board (Trapozoid)

Tags: java, swing, 3d

I'm working on a java GUI project and I need to move a character (JLabel with ImageIcon) in 3D board which is a trapezoid in 2D.
I'm using null layout.
To do so, I need to change the x coordinates when I move up and down, but I can't get the equation to change them properly.

Here is my code for moving the character.

```
private int x=0 , y=0;
private int velx = 0 , vely = 0;
private JButton[][] cells;
private int rows = 9, cols = 9;

public void moveUp()
{   
    int[] arr = { 8 , 6,4 , 2 , 0 ,0, -2 , -4 ,-6 , -8};
    vely -= h/50 ;
    velx += arr[cols];
    cells[rows][cols].setIcon(null);
    cells[--rows][cols].setIcon(position);
    width -= width/20;
    height-= height/20;
    character.setIcon(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon(
            icon).getImage()
            .getScaledInstance(width, height,
                    java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)))));
    character.setBounds(x+velx, y+vely, width, height);
}

public void moveDown()
{
    int[] arr = { 8 , 6,4 , 2 , 0,0 , -2 , -4 ,-6 , -8};
    vely += h/50;
    velx -= arr[cols];
    cells[rows][cols].setIcon(null);
    cells[++rows][cols].setIcon(position);
    width += width/20;
    height+= height/20;
    character.setIcon(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon(
            icon).getImage()
            .getScaledInstance(width, height,
                    java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)))));
    character.setBounds(x+velx, y+vely, width, height);
}

public void moveLeft()
{
    int[] arr = {45 , 46 , 47 , 48 , 50 , 56 , 57 ,58 , 59,60};
    velx -= arr[rows];//w/23;
    cells[rows][cols].setIcon(null);
    cells[rows][--cols].setIcon(position);
    character.setBounds(x+velx, y+vely, width, height);
}

public void moveRight()
{
    int[] arr = {45 , 46 , 47 , 48 , 50 , 56 , 57 ,58 , 59,60};
    velx +=arr[rows]; // w/23;
    cells[rows][cols].setIcon(null);
    cells[rows][++cols].setIcon(position);
    character.setBounds(x+velx, y+vely, width, height);
}
```

Comment: What happens with the current implementation?

Comment: when I move Up and down only or right and left only it works perfectly. However when I try multiple combinations of the 4 directions the character eventually gets outside of the board

Answer (score 0):

I can see one potential issue based on the information.
You don't zero `vely` when moving left or right, so any previous movement up or down will happen again.

Try setting `vely` to zero in  `moveLeft()` and `moveRight()`

Comment: If i zero vely then the character would move back to the original y coordinate